# Display datepicker/combobox instead of keyboard

Tags: iphone, titanium

I have a form with multiple textfields.
The majority of these textfields, when clicked, produce the standard behaviour by displaying the keyboard in the expected way.

However when some of these textfields are clicked, I would like to override the standard behaviour by displaying either:

```
1) A datepicker, or
2) A Combobox
```

**QUESTION 1:**

How do I override the standard behaviour and display a datepicker/combobox instead of the default keyboard?

**QUESTION 2:**

I currently have a situation where there may be both keyboard and datepicker/combobox (keyboard on top of datepicker/combobox or vice versa) displayed on screen at the same time.
How do I prevent this from occuring, as there should only be one or the other (default keyboard, or datepicker/combobox) being displayed at any given time.

PS I have viewed other questions on this site which are similar but they dont seem to answer my quesions.

Any comments/suggestions appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Implement textfiled delegates and in the delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField  
{  
   //Check the textfield for which you want to display date picker
    if(textField == datePickerTextField)
    {
       [self showDatePicker];
       return NO; //to disallow editing i.e it will not open keyboard
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have seen this code before but dont quite understand it. Questions: Where do I put this code, is "textFieldShouldBeginEditing" a function, if you could provide an explanation of this code I would be grateful;)

Comment: its a delegate method of UITextField , you should first gain the basics of iphone developement. For now just place this method I posted in the .m file where you are having your textfield. And do not forget to assign delegate for textfield i.e textField.delegate = self; This method will get called when you will click on textfield

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt You need create textfield. then its edit event blur that textfield and open your datepicker or combobox.
Thats method to hide keyboard & show datepicker in Titanium.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved via trick. 
To hide showing keyboard, set this property in text field.

```
enabled:false
```

And use text field click event to show date picker.